# How do I find the users number using binary search

Tags: java, binary-search

Prompt: Player chooses a range (both min and max), and then thinks of a number in that range (no need to type the number into the program). The game should use binary search to systematically guess the player’s number. The player should tell the computer “too high” or “too low” or “correct” between rounds. The program should continue until the computer gets the answer, or detects cheating (or knows the answer for sure). Before quitting, the computer should say how many “rounds” it was (how many guesses it took).

Problem: After the computer is wrong the first time and the user declares too high or too low, I can't ressign the values for an upper and lower range

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Think of a number");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = null;
        String y = null;
        String i = null;
        //Get the input from the player
        System.out.println("Please your maximum value");

        if (scan.hasNext()) {
            x = scan.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Please input your min value");
        if (scan.hasNext()) {
            y = scan.next();
        }

        //Parse the input so its usuable in the array
        int max = Integer.parseInt(x);
        int min = Integer.parseInt(y);

        boolean numberguessed = true; 
        int numberofRounds = 0;

        while(numberguessed) {
            int midpoint = (max+min)/2;

            numberofRounds++;

            System.out.println("Is your number " + midpoint + " please say too low or too high or correct");
             if (scan.hasNext()) {
                 i = scan.next();
             }
             if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("too high")) {
                 min = midpoint;
             }
             if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("too low")) {
                 max = midpoint;
                 min = 0;
             }
             if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("correct")) {
                 System.out.println("the number of rounds in this game is" + numberofRounds);
                 break;
             }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to ask the user to enter the `x` and `y` Max and min again ? after they finish their first round ?

Comment: still not working ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `scan.nextLine()` instead of `scan.next()` , to read everything in the line including `space` characters which is why the max and min are never set in the first place.

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

[More info on scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

To loop again the whole game, look at `do {} while(true);` iteration.

```
System.out.println("Think of a number");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String playAgain = "y";
String x = null;
String y = null;
String i = null;

do {
    // Get the input from the player
    System.out.println("Please your maximum value");

    if (scan.hasNext()) {
        x = scan.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Please input your min value");
    if (scan.hasNext()) {
        y = scan.next();
    }

    // Parse the input so its usuable in the array
    int max = Integer.parseInt(x);
    int min = Integer.parseInt(y);
    int midpoint = 0;
    boolean numberguessed = true;
    int numberofRounds = 0;

    while (numberguessed) {         
        midpoint = (max + min) / 2;
        numberofRounds++;
        System.out.println("Is your number " + midpoint
                + " please press (l) for too low or (h) for too high or (c) for correct");
        if (scan.hasNext()) {
            i = scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
            min = midpoint;
        } else if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
            max = midpoint;
            min = 0;
        } else if (i.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
            System.out.println("the number of rounds in this game is"
                    + numberofRounds);
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Press y to play again");
    if (scan.hasNext()) {
        playAgain = scan.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Game over");
} while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

[More info on do while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

A suggestion would be to use simple yes/no answers like h,l and c instead of asking users to write a word.  Let us know.

Comment: Instead of `do { } while (true)` I suggest to use the more idiomatic `while (true) do { }`. This doesn't leave the reader unsure about the breaking condition.